# android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Came across this error when navigating back from `FragB` to `FragA`.

This navigation has been working fine for a long time but has recently been throwing this error.

I have gone through all my resource layouts to double check there are no duplicate id's.

Answer (score 1):

`FragA`'s main view was a `ScrollView`

Changing `FragA`'s main view to a `RelativeLayout` and nesting the `ScrollView` within it solved the issue.

The reason it was working previously is that there was not enough views inside the `ScrollView` to make it scroll so no state had to be saved.

Comment: Had the same error when changing configuration between portrait and landscape with different layouts. Only the portrait layout had a scroll view as the root. Wrapping it with a FrameLayout solved the problem.Thanks for saving me the time to figure it out.